# Flight reservation for China visa

Tags: visas, air-travel, bookings, china

I am a British citizen, living in the UK and I am in the process of applying for a visa to China. I need to show flights into and out of China for the visa. I have already paid for return tickets to Hong Kong but I don't think that is enough for the visa. I could pay for cheap return tickets into Shanghai from HK and return them after I get my visa (this will cost about £25 in cancellation fees).

Alternatively, would it be acceptable to reserve new flights into mainland China from the UK using, for example, Turkish Airlines? (Note that I can get a reservation for the flights without paying for a week. It clearly states on the email that I will lose my tickets if I don't pay by a certain date.)

Thanks!

Comment: You live in the UK but need to show return flight into China? Return flight from where?

Comment: @Neusser I have edited it to, hopefully, make it clearer. Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean "a two-way journey" and not "a flight going back"?

Comment: @Neusser Two way journey; thanks for clarifying that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your flight to HK isn't enough indeed. You're basically in the situation of people living in HK, applying for a Chinese visa, but intending to go to somewhere close by, by road or train rather than by plane.

Not all Chinese consulates behave the same on this point. Some might have more flexibility in dealing with this. But, since you are applying for a Chinese visa, I suppose you **are** going to Mainland China. So depending on where you're going, you could for instance ask the consulate whether booking tickets on the [Kowloon through train](https://www.it3.mtr.com.hk/b2c/frmScheduleGuangdong.asp?strLang=Eng) would be acceptable.

If, on the other hand, you want to go to HK first, and then, at a later stage, book a cheap ticket to somewhere in China, you might as well apply for the visa in HK. Big travel agencies like CTS or TravelExpert will do it efficiently for you.

Comment: Thanks. Do you think the reservation into China that I mentioned would be enough?

Comment: The Turkish airlines ticket? Maybe, maybe not. They might notice it is only a pre-booking, not a firm reservation.

Answer (score 1):

> **I need to show flights into and out of China for the visa.**

Last time I travelled from UK to China via HK I flew to HK, stayed in HK a few days then in HK arranged bus tickets from HK to mainland China.

To obtain my visa while in the UK, I had details of accommodation booked in China, I did not have details of any transportation between HK and China, other than a mention of my intention to take a bus (a long distance bus, more like a coach in UK terms).